# Unable to generate Geoplot with latitudes and longitudes on google map using bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps, bokeh

I am trying to plot a set of latitudes and longitudes on the map of New York City using bokeh. Even though I have a Google Map API key, the rendered html file displays the map for a brief moment before generating an error message saying - "Oops! Something went wrong." The page is clearly unresponsive.

Here's the code below:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapOptions
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
import config


output_file("bokeh.html")
latitude_list = [40.7032670673495, 40.75261, 40.67599, 40.75638, 40.7765809, 40.730294, 40.7426589397899, 40.679911, 40.732283, 40.713046]
longitude_list = [-73.9922419276899, -73.97342, -74.01432, -73.97759, -73.9790791, -73.9835395, -74.0059285394953, -73.994879, -73.999284, -73.958968]

map_options = GMapOptions(lat=40.7128, lng=-74.0060, map_type="roadmap", zoom=4)
api_key = config.api_key
bokeh_plot = gmap(api_key, map_options, title = "Business locations")

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(lat = latitude_list,lon = longitude_list))
bokeh_plot.circle(x = "lon", y = "lat", size = 10, fill_alpha = 0.8, source = source)
show(bokeh_plot)
```

Does anyone have any clue about this ?

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with your browser or system in general - page crashes are really hard to cause with JS code. Your particular example works just fine for me.

Comment: That is definitely strange! I have tried opening the html file on different browsers - safari and chrome, and on both occasions, I've received the same error message. Is there a way to check what is wrong with the system ? I'm using macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've resolved this issue. I hadn't enabled the Maps JavaScript API. Once that was done, I could easily generate the plot without any difficulty.